# Checking to see if file exist in multiple locations

Tags: php

I have a two part question...

1. For my file check I need to look to see if the file is present in `$filechk` or `$dirchk`.
2. How can I use a wildcard on the file extension `$filename.*` when doing a file check?
   I'm using `is_file` because I read that it's twice as fast when checking if a file exists.

**code**

```
$filechk1 = "/temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$filechk2 = "/temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc";
$dirchk1 = "/temp/files/" . $IDname . $data[0] . ".doc";
$dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . $IDname . $data[1] . ".doc";            
if(is_file($filechk1) && ($filechk2)){
   ...
}
else { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, really: I dont understand you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get a list of all of the files in the directory and then check the file extensions - is_file is for a single file only.

Answer (score 1):

To check a number of files, just do a separate `is_file()` or `file_exists()` - the speed difference between the two is hardly relevant if you're doing this on one or two files.

For a wildcard search, do a [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob).

```
$files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.doc");
print_r($files);
```

Comment: i can apply the glob() to a file extension check too right? if i'm liking for all filename File001.* also when doing the directory check is there a method look for a directory disregard the case sensitivity? if I wanted to see if $filechk1 exist in /temp/files/$UserName/$filename how could I make the check disregard the case since linux can have the same folder names in upper/lower case characters

Comment: @acctman for a case insensitive search, you would have to do a glob on all files, lowercase all results, and then compare against the lowercased search term.

Comment: do you have an example of how to do this with glob() i'm not sure where to start